# number of possible component in sinusoidal model

Tags: stochastic-processes, signal-processing

suppose that we have following model

$y[t]=A_1(sin(\omega_1*t+\phi_1)+A_2*sin(\omega_2*t+\phi_2)+....+A_p*sin(\omega_p*t+\phi_p)$+$z(t)$

my question is not related how to determine number of   components,but i am interested what it could be in maximum,for  example let us consider that we have sampled this model and get sample with size let say $294$,question arises  what can be maximum number of component?for instance can it be more then $147?$,or more then half size of signal sample?or ic can be in generally something $20-50$ for instance?i am not exacting on exact number,but  possible maximum number which can be  in this case?thanks in advance